# Last record in a for-loop is not processed

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, sprite-kit

I have a strange problem when i am fixing the zPosition from an array in my code. The the last record, which is there as well as the actual sprite with the same name, is not loaded. All other sprites except the last works.

The code:

```
// Refresh the nodes
NSLog(@"#1 workingArray: %@", workingArray);
for (NSString *aCard in workingArray) {

    if ([aCard isEqualToString:[workingArray objectAtIndex:[workingArray count]-1]]) {
        NSLog(@"#2 Found %@", aCard); // To check that the record is present
    }

    SKNode *refreshNodeForZPos = [_background childNodeWithName:aCard];
    refreshNodeForZPos.name = aCard;
    refreshNodeForZPos.zPosition = zPosition;
    zPosition++;
    NSLog(@"#3 refreshNode:%@ + z:%.0f", refreshNodeForZPos.name, zPosition);
}
```

When looking at the #1 NSLog output I can see that the last record, "CJ" is there:

```
'#1' workingArray: (
C6b,
C2b,
CQb,
C8b,
CAb,
CKb,
C5b,
C10b,
C9b,
C4b,
C7b,
C3b,
CJ
```

The #2 NSLog just make sure I really find the record and the #3 is logging the loop:

```
'#3' refreshNode:C6b + z:1
'#3' refreshNode:C2b + z:2
'#3' refreshNode:CQb + z:3
'#3' refreshNode:C8b + z:4
'#3' refreshNode:CAb + z:5
'#3' refreshNode:CKb + z:6
'#3' refreshNode:C5b + z:7
'#3' refreshNode:C10b + z:8
'#3' refreshNode:C9b + z:9
'#3' refreshNode:C4b + z:10
'#3' refreshNode:C7b + z:11
'#3' refreshNode:C3b + z:12
'#2' Found CJ
'#3' refreshNode:(null) + z:13
```

The last record (z:13) is null and i do not understand why.

Comment: Done any debugging? Does `childNodeWithName` return a valid instance?

Comment: Is "[_background childNodeWithName:aCard]" returning nil when passed @"CJ"?

Comment: @Wain i have done debugging for a few hours :-) I did insert an NSLog on the childNodeWithName and it returns null for the last record.

Comment: @Brian Walker Brian yes.

Comment: So that is why you get a log of `null`. Not sure what you're looking for...

Comment: So the for-loop is working correctly. The problem is in another area of your code. Look at where you create the child nodes to make sure one is created for "CJ".

Comment: @Brian Walker ...you are right, i just identified the problem. See my answer description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian Walker correctly pointed out the problem was in an other part of the code, not the loop itself.

Each sprite is actually represented by two sprites: "CJb" (one example of a sprite) is the back side of the sprite and "CJ" is the front side of the sprite. They are all added onto the background. When double-clicking on a sprite the following happens:

1. I check if the sprite have a "b" in the end of the name, if so it is the back-side showing, if not it is the front side showing
2. I create a new SKSpriteNode with the front/back sprite that should be displayed and save it's credentials
3. I delete the "old" sprite and do an "addChild" of the new one and at the same time update the array with the names, that is used to set correct zPositions

**My mistake**

At the initial addChild all sprites were added this way:

```
[_background addChild: theSprite]
```

When i later swapped the sprite, from "CJb" to "CJ" i used:

```
[self addChild: theSprite]
```

...and then, after updating the "workingArray" processed the above code. After I changed the "self" back to "_background" in the addChild it all worked.

Summary: I must add the new sprites using the same background.

However, i still do not fully understand why it did not process the last record anyhow.

Also, a BIG thank you to @Brian Walker and @Wain :-)